# can not read .eslintrc.json file in vs code in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I'm using a .eslintrc.json file for my react.js project in my vs code editor in ubuntu platform, but, for some reasons the .eslintrc.json file can not be processed/read by the vs code editor. As soon as I open my project in vs code, I get this following error:

```
Cannot read config file: /home/[nonrootuser]/Desktop/react-projects/.eslintrc.json Error: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

The file permission and ownership has been properly set and it is the following:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 [nonrootuser] [nonrootuser]    748 Apr  5 09:34 .eslintrc.json
```

But, still the .eslintrc.json file is not being processed/read by the vs code editor.

My help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds more like your file is not well-formatted json.  Plug it into one of the online json formatters, like https://jsoneditoronline.org/.  Do you get any errors?

Comment: I've checked my .eslintrc.json into a json validator. It is 100% valid json file.

Comment: Where is the error showing up? In the terminal? If so, how are you opening the file in code - via the terminal or a dialog? Can you paste the contents of your `.eslintrc.json` into your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue which I fixed by copying the contents of `eslintrc.json` into a new file, deleting the old and renaming the new file to `eslintrc.json`. I also deleted the contents of `node_modules` and ran `npm install` but for some reason I had to explicitly run `npm install eslint-plugin-node --save-dev`.